# Optimizing above-the-fold CSS

Tags: html, css, optimization, google-pagespeed

I want to fix the "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content" requirement for better [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) score but I'm not quite sure what the best approach to this problem is.

- How can I best balance the page load for new visitors and returning visitors?
- When should I load my CSS asynchronously, when not?
- Should I maybe only inline CSS for small screens?

Relevant presentation: [Optimizing the Critical Rendering Path](http://youtu.be/YV1nKLWoARQ)

#### Example

Since inlining lots of CSS leads to slower page loads on subsequent visits, I could serve different versions for recurring visitors based on a cookie. For detecting above-the-fold CSS I could use the bookmarklet from this article: paul.kinlan.me/detecting-critical-above-the-fold-css/

For new visitors:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>New Visitor</title>
  <style><!-- insert above the fold css here --></style>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></noscript>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- insert content here -->
  <script>
    // load css
    var node = document.createElement('link');
    node.rel = 'stylesheet';
    node.href = 'style.css';
    document.head.appendChild(node);
    // set cookie
    var exp = new Date();
    exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + 3600 * 1000);
    document.cookie = 'returning=true; expires=' + exp.toUTCString() + '; path=/';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For returning visitors:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Returning Visitor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Any problems with this approach?

Comment: _“for better PageSpeed Insights score”_ – first of all, I would ask myself: Does my page _actually_ need to be optimized, or is what you wrote in that quote all it is – optimizing for a _score_’s sake, and not because there are any actual benefits for the user?

Comment: The performance improvement will be marginal if you use only 1 external stylesheet and therefore the time you will invest in optimizing it is wasted unless you're building the next Facebook. There are much more important things to bother with

Comment: Let's just say a page _does_ need to be optimized and all much more important things have already been done. How can I optimize CSS in the critical rendering path for not only better PageSpeed score but also actual page loading time and maybe even page rank?

Answer (score 1):

There is such a thing as over-optimizing. Your example approach adds unneeded complexity. What you should be looking at is a minimal stylesheet for the head section that will make everything above the fold make sense and conform to the design and layout (but not necessarily respect it 100%).

For the rest of the page just load the rest of the CSS at the end of the page and you should be fine. If what matters to you is above the fold, then so does the first CSS you load. Everything else can be delayed.